# Group by in R (grouping in one table and matching it with another table)

Tags: r

I have following set of data in R in table A

```
ID  Balance
1   100  
1   200 
2   200
3   500
4   900
4   400
4   300
5   500
```

and I have another table B having only unique IDs (1,2,3,4,5). I want to group by IDs and sum balance from table A and put it in Table B (adding a new column Balance). something like this:

```
ID  Balance
1    300
2    200
3    500
4    1600
5    500
```

Request you to help me out with this. Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `data.table` solution

```
setkey(setDT(A), ID)
setkey(setDT(B), ID)
B <- B[A[, list(Balance = sum(Balance)), by = ID]]
```

---

A base R solution

```
B <- merge(B, aggregate(Balance ~ ID, A, sum), by = "ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
B <- A %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(Balance=sum(Balance))
```

With the `plyr` package you can achieve the same result:

```
library(plyr)
B <- ddply(A, .(ID), summarise, Balance=sum(Balance))
```

Warning: don't load the `dplyr` and `plyr` packages together! Use one or the other.